# Integration over a ball (PDE Evans)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Im reading Evans PDEs second edition.

On page 28 Theorem 6, we are proving that if $u\in C(U)$ and satisfies the mean-value property for each ball $B(x,r) \subset U$ then $$u\in C^{\infty}(U)$$

Now before I ask my question let me clear some things up:
$\eta$ is the standard molifier, and $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$, and lastly $n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}$ is the volume of $dB(0,r)$

In the last step of the proof we use that 
$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\cdot\eta(\frac{r}{\epsilon})\cdot n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}dr=\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(y)dy$$

What change of variables is going on ?

EDIT 1 :

Following the advice of a comment, could  I add in the step

$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\cdot\eta(\frac{r}{\epsilon})\cdot n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}dr=\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}} (\int_{dB(0,r)} \eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})dS(x) ) dr  =\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(y)dy$$

Comment: Spherical coordinates are used. Integrating on a ball means integrating from $0$ to $r$ and then integrating on every sphere of given radius between $0$ and $r$. Since the mollifier function is constant on spheres since it is radial, you have the area of the sphere which appears.

Comment: So my edit basically ?

Comment: Yes. It's just a change of variables noting that your function is constant on spheres.